# How to localstorage set users data (Problem with OPTIONS before post)

Tags: reactjs, post, axios

I got problem with `axios.post`. How to resolve that?

[image]

This is POST mapping return values.

But first request is OPTIONS http request

[image]

This is OPTIONS resp value.

Then I accessed `window.localstorage.getItem("username", username)` then return Undefined.

```
export const doLogin = (body) => {
    console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_DB_HOST);

    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {"Content-Type": `application/json`},
        data: body,
        url: process.env.REACT_APP_DB_HOST + "/login",
    };

    axios(options).then((res) =>{
        const token = res.headers.authorization;
        const username = res.headers.username;
        const nickname = res.headers.nickname;
        console.log("===================")
        window.localStorage.setItem("token", token);
        window.localStorage.setItem("username", username);
        window.localStorage.setItem("nickname", nickname);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem cause when you load page your localstorage is empty and when you ad new item to it, it will added but when you want to read that from localstorage it will give you the value that you had in loading time,
if I'm right you have 2 options:

1.use redux and redux-presist to overcome this challenge

2.use function to get value from localstorage, forexample:

```
  const getUsername = () => localStorage.getItem('username');

  AxiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(config => {
   config.headers['username'] = 'Bearer ' + getUsername();
   return config;
  });
```

here I'm using axios interceptors to send header in request but in any way you work with you can use this form of getting value from localStorage

Comment: Thanks you for answer! 
I solved with Backend (Spring)
It' was wrong in CorsConfig ( I just add this!)

 config.addExposedHeader("*");

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your attention! 
I solved with `Backend` (Spring) 
It' was wrong in `CorsConfig` ( I just add this!)

---

```
 config.addExposedHeader("*")
```